# Getting Access Denied message while calling http post service

Tags: android, web-services, http-headers, http-post

I am getting the 401 Access denied message while calling the HTTP post service.In Postman getting the Result but while calling through the service it is displaying access denied message. Please, anyone, help me to resolve my issue.

Here is My code.

```
   try {
     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://site:ab4aca652284d7dc87ca1f347f2ac432@ori-eu-west-1.searchly.com/devkoopicafenetecco-2/_search");
     request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
     JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject();

     myjson.put("from", 0);
     myjson.put("size", 10);

     StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(myjson.toString());

     entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/json; charset=utf-8"));

     request.setEntity(entity);

     final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);

     HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
     InputStream instream = response.getEntity().getContent();
     String tempresult = convertStreamToString(instream);
     instream.close();
     result = tempresult.toString();

} catch (Exception ex) {
     Log.e("exception","ex"+ex);
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Does your URL require any cookies? As Postman might have added but in your http request you have to.

Comment: When Anonymous access authentication is turned off for the Web service application, all the caller applications must provide the credentials before making any request. By default, the Web service client proxy does not inherit the credentials of the security context where the Web service client application is running.  https://community.nintex.com/community/build-your-own/nintex-for-office-365/blog/2015/05/14/o365-call-http-web-service-failed-unauthorized-access-denied

Comment: in ios also it displaying the responce

Answer (score 0):

You can check and add 'User-Agent' when you sending your request.Like this:

```
 url = new URL(urlStr);
      HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Pk");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

or

```
 request.setheader("User-Agent","PK");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
try {
            String url = "https://site:ab4aca652284d7dc87ca1f347f2ac432@ori-eu-west-1.searchly.com/devkoopicafenetecco-2/_search";
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    sslContext,
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            CloseableHttpClient client= HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                    .build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

            request.addHeader("Accept", "   */*");
            request.addHeader("User-Agent", "runscope/0.1");
            request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic c2l0ZTphYjRhY2E2NTIyODRkN2RjODdjYTFmMzQ3ZjJhYzQzMg==");

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            System.out.println(result.toString());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("exception","ex"+ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```